# The content is not consistent on both side of Silverlight domain service implementation

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have implemented one methods of alarms retrieval and the total of alarms are 601800 records but when I made a call from client (SilverLight) to domain service (server) I can get all alarms with right total but the content is not consistent.

On the server, I have made a filter of case alarms having ID 790, 2997 and found over 10.000 for case 790, over 6000 for case 2997. But when I receive the result of LoadOperation.Completed callback function, there was no alarms for case 790 and wrong alarms for case 2997, it was about over 15000, but the total of all alarms was the same with on the server-side. 
Here is my short codes:
Server:

```
public IEnumerable<RollingAlarmDTO> GetRollingAlarmsByFilterWithoutSites(List<int> statusCode, DateTime fromTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        var list = (from s in this.ObjectContext.Site//.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Address))
                    join rh in this.ObjectContext.SNMPReceiverHistory on s.Address equals rh.IPAddress
                    where
                    (s.Address != null && !s.Address.Equals(string.Empty)) &&
                    ((fromTime > DateTime.MinValue ? rh.ReceiveTime >= fromTime : true) &&
                    (endTime > DateTime.MinValue ? rh.ReceiveTime <= endTime : true)) &&
                    statusCode.Contains(rh.EventType)
                    select new RollingAlarmDTO
                    {
                        SNMPTrapID = rh.SNMPTrapID,
                        TimeStamp = rh.TimeStamp,
                        ReceiveTime = rh.ReceiveTime,
                        Description = rh.AlarmDescription,
                        Status = rh.EventType,
                        SiteDescription = s.Description,
                        SiteID = s.ID
                    }).ToList();  

        var case_790 = list.Where(s => s.SiteID == 790).ToList();
        var case_2997 = list.Where(s => s.SiteID == 2997).ToList();
        return list;

    }
```

And the client-side:

```
 private void FilterAlarmReloadedPerformed(string alarmStatus, DateTime fromTime, DateTime endTime, List<Site> selectedSite, int skip)
    {
        var loadOperation = this.dataContext.Load(this.dataContext.GetRollingAlarmsByFilterQuery(AlarmStatus.GetStatusCode(alarmStatus), getListSiteID(selectedSite), fromTime, endTime), LoadBehavior.RefreshCurrent, true);
        loadOperation.Completed += (sender, ex) =>
                   {
                       if (loadOperation.HasError)
                       { }
                       else
                       {

                           var case_790 = loadOperation.Entities.Where(s => s.SiteID == 790).ToList();
                           var case_2997 = loadOperation.Entities.Where(s => s.SiteID == 2997).ToList();
                           var listRollingAlarm = loadOperation.Entities;
                       }
                   };
    }
```

I have mentioned about the size of data contract but not working, but i don't know whether my setting was right:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<domainServices>
  <endpoints>
    <add name="OData" type="System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.ODataEndpointFactory, System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.OData, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </endpoints>
</domainServices>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RemoteEntry-Web-DomainService">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="MultisiteMonitor.Web.DataServices" behaviorConfiguration="RemoteEntry-Web-DomainService" />
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Thanks in advance so much for any your helps, explainations !